# How to create upgrade schema file second time

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, upgradeschema

I want to create a new upgrade schema file in magento2. I already used the install schema and upgrade schema. I need to create a new upgrade schema.

Comment: For which version you want?

Comment: What is the meaning of second time I don't get it If you already have one upgradeschema file then you have to put your version changes in that file this question seem to be unclear

Answer (score 1):

See the example UpgradeSchema.php below

```
<?php
    namespace XXX\YYY\Setup;

    use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

    class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
    {
        public function upgrade(
            SchemaSetupInterface $setup,
            ModuleContextInterface $context
        ) {
            $installer = $setup;

            $installer->startSetup();
            if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), "1.0.0", "<")) {
            //Your upgrade script
            }
            if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {
              // your old upgrade script
            }
            $installer->endSetup();
        }
    }`
```

So Everytime you write a upgrade script, Compare your version with the current version and if "Less than" then proceed with your script

```
if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), "1.0.0", "<")) {
                //Your upgrade script
                }
```

Also, everytime when you add a upgrade script change the setup_version in etc/module.xml and run the upgrade command.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `declarative schema` from magento 2.3

File path: `VendorName/ModuleName/etc/db_schema.xml`

Install schema Example :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="test" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="CMS Block To Store Linkage Table">
        <column xsi:type="smallint" name="id" padding="6" unsigned="false" nullable="false" identity="false"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="name" nullable="true" length="255" comment="name"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="id"/>
        </constraint>
    </table>
</schema>
```

Refer : [Magento 2.3 Devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/migration-commands.html)

Must read about `db_schema_whitelist.json` file for Backward compatibility